# What goes in the code pointer of a colon definition?

Tags: forth

The code pointer as described in Leo Brodie's *[Starting FORTH](http://www.forth.com/starting-forth/)*:

> In the case of a colon definition, the pointer points to code that executes the rest of the words in the colon definition. In practice there are many ways to implement this concept, including native code realizations.

What does that mean though? Is that a pointer to an interpreter type word such as `execute`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Brodie says, there are *many* ways to implement this. For an excellent explanation of several of them, see Brad Rodriguez's ["Moving Forth" series](http://www.bradrodriguez.com/papers/moving1.htm).

For a (perhaps overly detailed) explanation of direct threading in particular, see *[Direct Threading in TransForth](https://youtu.be/vmjo6gesmUk)*.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

In an ordinary threaded implementation, it's most likely a pointer to raw machine code. The machine code will typically save the inner interpreter instruction pointer onto the return stack, and then load the instruction pointer with a new value which points to the beginning of the threaded code for the called word.

In pseudo assembly language for a 32-bit machine:

```
\ R is a register holding the return stack pointer
\ I is a register holding the inner interpreter instruction pointer
\ W is a register pointing to the code field of the word to be executed
\ NEXT is a macro that implements the inner interpreter
sub R, R, #4
mov (R), I
add I, W, #4
NEXT
```

`NEXT` might expand into

```
mov W, (I)
add I, I, #4
jmp (W)
```